# Работа со модулями qt

Tags: qt

возникла следующая проблема - есть проект, который использует модули qt charts и datavisualisation. При сборке проект не запускается на машинах без этих модулей отсюда вопрос - как "подложить" их к проекту или каким-то другим образом решить проблему? И да, я полнейший профан

Comment: как вариант установить данные модули (libQt5Charts5 и libQt5DataVisualization5) на тех системах где запускается приложение

Comment: К сожалению не вариант - как раз хотят чтобы эти модули шли комплектом

Comment: Вот как бы их упаковать вместе с проектом

Comment: ну собери их все в папку с приложением

Comment: А кто хочет? Что значит комплектом? Статическая линковка или динамические библиотеки, которые лежат рядом?

Comment: Я на всякий случай дам [эту ссылку](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment.html).

Comment: Просто я отвечаю больше не за прогу, а за механику происходящего внутри - отсюда и проф непригодность в плане каких-то элементарных вещей связанных со сборкой проектов. Ушел разбираться со статической линковкой

Comment: Какая конечная ОС. Если Windows, то вам нужна утилита windeployqt  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: Статическая линковка - зло, я отказался от неё несколько лет назад. К тому же для статической линковки проекта необходимо пересобрать весь qt со всеми библиотеками.

Comment: И все таки не понятна задача. Речь идёт о распространении приложения? Если да, то правильный путь windeployqt + Qt Installer framework

Comment: "И все таки не понятна задача. Речь идёт о распространении приложения? Если да, то правильный путь windeployqt + Qt Installer framework"
Да, вы верно поняли, спасибо за Qt Installer framewor - сейчас посмотрю как пользоваться